# How do I handle updates having installed digiKam using PPAs?

Tags: 10.10, package-management, ppa, partial-upgrade

In Ubuntu 10.10 I [installed digiKam](http://scribblesandsnaps.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/install-the-latest-beta-of-digikam-on-ubuntu-10-10/):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:philip5/extra
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:philip5/kubuntu-backports
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install digikam2 kipi-plugins2
```

When running the Update Manager, I am informed:

```
Not all updates can be installed
Run a partial upgrade, to install as many updates as possible
This can be caused by:
* A previous upgrade which didn't complete
* Problems with some of the installed software
* Unofficial software packages no provided by Ubuntu
* Normal changes of a pre-release version of Ubuntu
```

I click 'Close' rather than 'Partial Upgrade', and I can then select which of the updates to install. However, some are greyed out, including some "important security updates": Complete Generic Linux kernel, Generic Linux kernel headers and Generic Linux kernel image. Also, tortoisehg PPA updates from another PPA are greyed out.

How should I go about making sure the core Ubuntu system and my other packages installed via PPA are updated whilst still having digiKam installed (and preferably updated via PPA, too)?

I've been using Ubuntu for a while, but am not familiar with all the ins and outs of package management.

If I should include output from apt-get, please let me know. Thanks.

**Edit:** updating with terminal output:

```
sudo apt-get -V upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
   kdebase-runtime (4.5.1-0ubuntu3.1 => 4.6.1-0ubuntu1~maverick1~ppa1)
   ksysguard (4.5.1-0ubuntu8 => 4.6.1-0ubuntu1~maverick1~ppa1)
   ksysguardd (4.5.1-0ubuntu8 => 4.6.1-0ubuntu1~maverick1~ppa1)
   libksgrd4 (4.5.1-0ubuntu8 => 4.6.1-0ubuntu1~maverick1~ppa1)
   libksignalplotter4 (4.5.1-0ubuntu8 => 4.6.1-0ubuntu1~maverick1~ppa1)
   libprocessui4a (4.5.1-0ubuntu8 => 4.6.1-0ubuntu1~maverick1~ppa1)
   linux-generic (2.6.35.27.35 => 2.6.35.28.36)
   linux-headers-generic (2.6.35.27.35 => 2.6.35.28.36)
   linux-image-generic (2.6.35.27.35 => 2.6.35.28.36)
   plasma-scriptengine-javascript (4.5.1-0ubuntu3.1 => 4.6.1-0ubuntu1~maverick1~ppa1)
   tortoisehg (1.1.1-1 => 2.0+repack-0ppa1~maverick1)
   tortoisehg-nautilus (1.1.1-1 => 2.0+repack-0ppa1~maverick1)
   vlc (1.1.4-1ubuntu1.4 => 1.1.8-maverick~ppa1)
   vlc-nox (1.1.4-1ubuntu1.4 => 1.1.8-maverick~ppa1)
   vlc-plugin-notify (1.1.4-1ubuntu1.4 => 1.1.8-maverick~ppa1)
   vlc-plugin-pulse (1.1.4-1ubuntu1.4 => 1.1.8-maverick~ppa1)
The following packages will be upgraded:
   akonadi-server (1.5.0-0ubuntu1~maverick1~ppa1 => 1.5.1-0ubuntu1~maverick1~ppa1)
   gtk2-engines-equinox (1.30-ubuntu3 => 1.40)
   kompare (4.5.1-0ubuntu3 => 4.6.1-0ubuntu1~maverick1~ppa1)
   libakonadiprotocolinternals1 (1.5.0-0ubuntu1~maverick1~ppa1 => 1.5.1-0ubuntu1~maverick1~ppa1)
   libgpg-error0 (1.6-1ubuntu2 => 1.10-0ubuntu2~maverick1~ppa1)
   liborc-0.4-0 (0.4.11-1~maverick1 => 0.4.11-maverick~ppa1)
   libschroedinger-1.0-0 (1.0.10-1~maverick1 => 1.0.10-maverick~ppa1)
   libvlc5 (1.1.4-1ubuntu1.4 => 1.1.8-maverick~ppa1)
   libvlccore4 (1.1.4-1ubuntu1.4 => 1.1.8-maverick~ppa1)
   nvidia-current (260.19.06-0ubuntu1 => 260.19.36-maverick~ppa1)
   nvidia-current-modaliases (260.19.06-0ubuntu1 => 260.19.36-maverick~ppa1)
   nvidia-settings (260.19.06-0ubuntu1 => 260.19.29-maverick~ppa1)
   policykit-1-gnome (0.96-2ubuntu4 => 0.99-1ubuntu1~maverick1~ppa1)
   qapt-batch (1.0.3-0ubuntu2 => 1.1.1-0ubuntu1~maverick2)
   transmission-common (2.04-0ubuntu2 => 2.22-maverick~ppa1)
   vlc-data (1.1.4-1ubuntu1.4 => 1.1.8-maverick~ppa1)
16 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
Need to get 57.9MB of archives.
After this operation, 5,988kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

[image: Update Manager having added digiKam PPAs]

The top five packages in the screenshot are greyed out. It seems like packages from the digiKam PPAs I've added are blocking(?) packages that would otherwise be updated. Ideally, I would like to use the PPAs concerning digiKam only for digiKam itself (and its actual dependencies) but not other packages such as the nVidia driver and transmission and whatnot, and allow other standard packages from Ubuntu 10.10 to be used as normal.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` from the terminal, this will give you a list of packages to update and/or remove in case of conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the philip5-extra PPA contains not only Digikam, but also backports of other important packages. If you trust the repository, the upgrade should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Before I go ahead (will take a backup anyway), do you know if the other PPAs I use like the tortoisehg might become usable again once the "partial" upgrade is done?

Answer (score 0):

Just go for the partial upgrade and it will be ok and updated .
I have had a similar situation and it became ok after the partial upgrade.

Comment: I've been wondering how safe that is, so thanks for your reply. I'll take a backup image of the system partition and give it a go and report back.